# C4 navigating back and forth between subviews

Tags: ios, navigation, subviews, c4

I feel silly again but I don't manage to navigate back and forth between the subviews of my project. I can add as many subviews as I want as long as it just goes forward, but as soon as I want to come back to one of the views previously visited I have a problem...
here is my simplified code:

**C4Workspace.h**

```
#import "C4CanvasController.h"
#import "FirstView.h"
@interface C4WorkSpace : C4CanvasController{
    FirstView *firstView;
}
@end
```

**C4Workspace.m**

```
#import "C4Workspace.h"

@implementation C4WorkSpace

-(void)setup {
    firstView=[FirstView new];
    firstView.canvas.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, self.canvas.width, self.canvas.height);
    firstView.canvas.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    [firstView setup];
    firstView.mainCanvas=self.canvas;
    [self.canvas addSubview:firstView.canvas];
}

@end
```

**FirstView.h**

```
#import "C4CanvasController.h"
#import "SecondView.h"

@interface FirstView : C4CanvasController{
    C4Label *goToSecondView;
    SecondView *secondView;

}
@property (readwrite, strong) C4Window *mainCanvas;

@end
```

**FirstView.m**

```
#import "FirstView.h"
@implementation FirstView
-(void)setup{
    goToSecondView=[C4Label labelWithText:@"go to second View"];
    goToSecondView.origin=CGPointMake(20, 50);
    [self.canvas addLabel:goToSecondView];
    [self listenFor:@"touchesBegan" fromObject:goToSecondView andRunMethod:@"goToSecondView"];
}
-(void)goToSecondView{
    [goToSecondView removeFromSuperview];
    C4Log(@"second view");
    secondView=[SecondView new];
    secondView.canvas.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, self.canvas.width, self.canvas.height);
    secondView.canvas.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    [secondView setup];
    secondView.mainCanvas=self.canvas;
    [self.canvas addSubview:secondView.canvas];  
}
@end
```

**SecondView.h**

```
#import "C4CanvasController.h"
#import "FirstView.h"
@interface SecondView : C4CanvasController{
    C4Label *goToFirstView;
    FirstView *firstView;
}
@property (readwrite, strong) C4Window *mainCanvas;
@end
```

**SecondView.m**

```
#import "SecondView.h"
@implementation SecondView
-(void)setup{
    goToFirstView=[C4Label labelWithText:@"go to First View"];
    goToFirstView.origin=CGPointMake(20, 50);
    [self.canvas addLabel:goToFirstView];
    [self listenFor:@"touchesBegan" fromObject:goToFirstView andRunMethod:@"goToFirstView"];
}

-(void)goToFirstView{
    [goToFirstView removeFromSuperview];
    C4Log(@"first view");
    firstview=[FirstView new];
    firstview.canvas.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, self.canvas.width, self.canvas.height);
    firstView.canvas.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    [firstView setup];
    firstView.mainCanvas=self.canvas;
    [self.canvas addSubview:firstView.canvas];   
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're over complicating the procedure.

The "control" of which subview should be done by the *containing view controller*, so, if the two views are on the canvas then it should be the canvas that deals with the switching instead of the objects themselves.

Thing to help improve your approach:

1. Get rid of references to the canvas from the subclasses.
2. The views of your subclassed controllers all post `touchesBegan` notifications... Use these in the workspace i.e. `[self listenFor:@"touchesBegan" fromObject:firstOrSecondView.canvas and runMethod:@"switch:"];`
3. Switch by either changing the `zPosition` or hiding / revealing the appropriate view...

I reduced your implementations to the following:

**FirstView.m**

```
#import "FirstView.h"
@implementation FirstView
-(void)setup{
    goToSecondView=[C4Label labelWithText:@"go to second View"];
    goToSecondView.origin=CGPointMake(20, 50);
    [self.canvas addLabel:goToSecondView];
    goToSecondView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
}
@end
```

**SecondView.m**

```
#import "SecondView.h"
@implementation SecondView
-(void)setup{
    goToFirstView=[C4Label labelWithText:@"go to First View"];
    goToFirstView.origin=CGPointMake(20, 50);
    [self.canvas addLabel:goToFirstView];
    goToFirstView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
}
@end
```

**C4WorkSpace.m**

```
#import "C4Workspace.h"
#import "FirstView.h"
#import "SecondView.h"

@implementation C4WorkSpace {
    FirstView *firstView;
    SecondView *secondView;
}

-(void)setup {
    firstView=[FirstView new];
    firstView.canvas.frame = self.canvas.frame;
    [firstView setup];
    firstView.canvas.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self.canvas addSubview:firstView.canvas];

    secondView=[SecondView new];
    secondView.canvas.frame = self.canvas.frame;
    [secondView setup];
    secondView.canvas.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self.canvas addSubview:secondView.canvas];

    secondView.canvas.hidden = YES;

    [self listenFor:@"touchesBegan"
        fromObjects:@[firstView.canvas, secondView.canvas]
       andRunMethod:@"switchView:"];
}

-(void)switchView:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    C4View *v = (C4View *)aNotification.object;

    if([v isEqual:firstView.canvas]) {
        firstView.canvas.hidden = YES;
        secondView.canvas.hidden = NO;
    } else {
        firstView.canvas.hidden = NO;
        secondView.canvas.hidden = YES;
    }
}

@end
```

This should work for you in the case that your views need differing functionality, like `FirstView` will have significantly different internal functionality than `SecondView`... If they are the same then you should think about collapsing them into the same subclass.

Comment: yes, this works as such but now the user can tab anywhere on the screen and will get to the other view. I would need to access the exact element of the other canvas (as there are other interactions on that canvas happening) and switch the views then.If there is a way to do so, that approach would be much easier...

Comment: about the need of different views: I'm trying to rebuild a new version of this: http://vimeo.com/58437447. So I'm having quite some different views here. I think it makes it much easier to understand the different states of the app if they can be found in different files/views, right?

Comment: answering my questions myself now: ok. So I suppose posting Notifications between those views is the method if I want only a specific object in that view to change from one view to another...Don't know if it makes sense to share that code later. Maybe others run into similar problems?

Comment: but one more question: I am kind of worried about the performance of the app as I will have quite many different views. Maybe that relates to the comment about the different views above: does it make sense to have different views for all different states? This might be an issue of performance vs. code legibility...

Comment: Nice video! I have a better idea of what you're getting at now.

Comment: **re: whole canvas** I'm skeptical about an entire canvas for each image element that you're putting on the screen. In general, I would suggest one canvas for each "screen"... so the alphabet screen has a canvas, with a bunch of subclassed C4Images for letters on it each of which broadcasts a `touchesBegan`. But, to answer your q about how to get the specific element, I would create a property for your label in your `.h` file, then you can say `listenFor:@".." from:controller.canvas.label runMethod:@".."`

Comment: Yes, it makes sense if your app is structured in a more broken-down way. But, the overuse of controllers will make it confusing as well. Every visible object in C4 is a view itself, so I would suggest thinking about how to use individual controllers to control a set of views that all do a similar thing.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39931/discussion-between-c4-travis-and-sumi)